# Save HTML tag <td> data from website using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to save the song title from the URL: https://onlineradiobox.com/us/977todayshits/playlist

I used the below code to fetch data

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://onlineradiobox.com/us/977todayshits/playlist");
    $matches = array();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<table class="tablelist-schedule" role="log">(.*?)<\/table>/s', $html, $matches,PREG_SET_ORDER );
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);
    echo "</pre>";
```

The result from the above Code:

```
Live    Mark Ronson - Nothing Breaks Like a Heart (feat. Miley Cyrus)
10:41   Camila Cabello - Consequences
10:38   Imagine Dragons - It's Time
10:34   Panic! at the Disco - High Hopes
10:31   Selena Gomez - Hands to Myself
```

This code gets the data but I don't know how will I save the 2nd td tag value in a table. It is not necessary that 2nd td will be a link when it is not linked then there is no class defined in td tag.

Comment: Can you be more specific in what exactly you need help with? Do you want to save the data in a database table, or two a file, or displayed on HTML page?

Comment: That does not look like the output from `print_r`. You need to clarify what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Just updated the question.
`<table class="tablelist-schedule" role="log">
 <tbody>
 <tr class="active">
 <td class="tablelist-schedule__time"><span class="time--schedule">Live</span></td>
 <td><a href="/track/432457390181261174/" class="ajax">Ariana Grande - God is a Woman</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="tablelist-schedule__time"><span class="time--schedule">16:34</span></td>
 <td><a href="/track/2527/" class="ajax">Nico &amp; Vinz - Am I Wrong</a></td>
</tr>`

So here 
1st td tag gives time 
2nd gives the name/title

I want to save the Title in my database

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Denis V said, don't use RegEx to parse html/xml content, use a proper lib for this, like LibXML...

Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('https://onlineradiobox.com/us/977todayshits/playlist'));

$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xPath->query('//table[@class="tablelist-schedule"]/tbody/tr/td[2]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->textContent . "\n";
}
```

Prints...

> Pitbull - Time Of Our Lives (feat. Ne Yo)
>
> Ellie Goulding - Close to Me (x Diplo feat. Swae Lee)
>
> Post Malone & Swae Lee - Sunflower
>
> Why Don't We - 8 Letters
>
> NF - Lie
>
> ... list too long...